# Zookeeper or Marathon docker container using 100% CPU

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, marathon

I am running a local docker-compose setup which has one Zookeeper container (latest is fetched) and one Marathon container (v1.1.0). Since last month whenever I up my containers my CPU usage goes to 100% after couple of minutes even after I keep it idle and not do any operations.

My setup - Ubuntu 17.10 with docker-ce 18.03.0 and docker-compose 1.21.0

Running top gives me this -

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                        
 7055 root      20   0 4527380 446644  45836 S  99.0  6.5   2:10.43 java
```

ps aux | grep java gives this -

```
harry     6928  0.1  0.6 3227008 47656 ?       Ssl  16:00   0:02 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=. -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../build/classes:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.11.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/conf: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /conf/zoo.cfg
root      7055 11.9  6.6 4527380 459896 ?      Ssl  16:00   3:35 java -jar /marathon/bin/../target/marathon-assembly-1.1.1.jar --master local --zk zk://zookeeper:2181/marathon --event_subscriber http_callback
harry     8551  0.0  0.0  15376  1068 pts/4    S+   16:30   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

I have confirmed with my colleagues running OSX and the same setup isn't affecting them. So this has to do something with the marathon or zookeeper container doing something wrong on Ubuntu.

Comment: I need more information about your computer, not only about software. For example, number of cores (`/proc/cpuinfo`)
With that, you can execute `docker run` with `--cpus`, `--cpu-quota` or `--cpuset-cpus` options.

Comment: @AlexGalera 2 cores - G4400T. Yeah I think forcing CPU limitation could be a good solution. Let me try it out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should check if 100% is mainly due to your container execution or other programs in host.
It's not very clear if your cpu load is caused by containers proccess or host process, so, I'll set out both possibilities.

**If high cpu load is mainly caused by containers**.

In this case, you should run docker containers limiting cpu load (quota) for host:

```
docker run --cpu-quota (int value) ...
```

Of course, it's also useful set a docker execution on a concrete core/cpu of your host. For example:

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus 0,1,5 ...
docker run --cpuset-cpus 0-4 ...
```

**If you want to priorize docker execution in case a high load:**
It'll be useful launch docker container specifying how many 
 cpus you want to reserve for your docker container. :

```
NCPUS=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`
docker run --cpus [float number between 0 and $NCPUS] ...
```

Note that 100% of all cpu cores is equivalent to execute docker run --cpus $NCPUS, but this is not possible obviously because your system needs some cpu usage.
Furthermore, if you use equivalent option with swarm replicas, for instance, replicas will only start if there's enough cpu resources. See documentation:
[docker info](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler)

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it on my setup everytime I run the containers, so I am pretty sure it is the containers. However, it is not reproducible on different more powerful hardware.